# Workers and multithreading with large image data

Tags: javascript

Does anyone have any idea how i can access a loaded texture from multiple threads? I need the texture values ​​for topological calculations in each thread. Passing the same OffScreenCanvas with the texture in it to every constructor in every thread doesn’t seem very efficient to me since I’m flooding the cache with unnecessary clones of the same texture or OffScreenCanvas. With a small texture it is ok, but the way is still not elegant. So i’m looking for a way to access a loaded texture from all treads. I don’t need the texture for renderings. For me, the texture is just a large database that I would like to be able to access the pixel values ​​from every thread.

Comment: So you want the pixel data, not the texture, right? If so you can store that data in a SharedArrayBuffer. If you wanted to share the bitmap (I.e the "texture"), you could transfer an ImageBitmap between each thread, but that might be cumbersome at some point. Note that your OffscreenCanvas idea wouldn't work though, once you've got a context from it it can't be transferred anymore.

Comment: Exactly, I just want to be able to readonly the pixel datas from the main thread in each subthread. I'm trying to get SharedArrayBuffer working in my app. It's not that easy to find an example with step-by-step instructions on what I need to add where in my code to make it work. I keep finding this:

Cross-Origin Embedder Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin Opener Policy: same-origin

Just writing that in my html header doesn't work. Adding that to the header must mean something else

Comment: Yes, it's in your HTTP response headers that you need to set these.